# How to access members in typeof instance of Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using `MatDialog` of angular material for popup in my application. Here, I have created a parent popup component `ParentComponent` where I pass `ChildComponent` as a parameter and access this child component in the constructor of the parent component. However, the type of this parameter is `typeof`. I want to access the members, ex: `TestFunction` inside of child component into Parent component using this `typeof` instance.

Basically, I have popup's close method that should call `TestFunction()` of save button child component.
[image]
Here's the code:

1. Passing child component as parameter to parent component:

   ```
   constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog){}
   let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(ParentComponent, {
     data: { component: ChildComponent }
   });
   ```
2. ChildComponent:

   ```
   TestFunction(){ console.log('test message')}
   ```
3. Accessing in parent component:

   ```
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ParentComponent>,
             @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

     ngOnInit() {
        console.log('data in component: ',this.data.prototype);

        this.data.TestFunction();

    }
   ```

Inside the console of child component, I get:

```
data in component:  
{component: ƒ}
component: class ChildComponent
ctorParameters: () => {…}
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 3
```

But I want TestFunction().

Comment: the ``matDialogRef`` returned when opening the dialog has a property ``componentInstance`` through which you can access your component's functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourComponent>;

this.dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(YourComponent, {
     disableClose: false
});

// Child Functionality
this.dialogRef.componentInstance.TestFunction()
```

Comment: I am getting `componentInstance` as undefined

Comment: Can you please upload your relevant code with the changes from yesterday?  Following the same pattern in my own code yields a defined component

Comment: Noice!  Glad to hear